# Can't add second interface to the pod with multus - minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, cni

I am trying to deploy a pod with second interface using multus-cni. However, when I deploy my pod I only see just one interface the main one. The secondary interface is not created.

I followed the steps in the quick start guide to install multus.

Environment:
minikube v1.12.1 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
Kubernetes v1.18.3 on Docker 19.03.12

**Multus version**
--cni-version=0.3.1

**$00-multus.conf**

```
{ "cniVersion": "0.3.1", "name": "multus-cni-network", "type": "multus", "kubeconfig": "/etc/cni/net.d/multus.d/multus.kubeconfig", "delegates": [ { "cniVersion": "0.3.1", "name":
"bridge", "type": "bridge", "bridge": "bridge", "addIf": "true", "isDefaultGateway": true, "forceAddress": false, "ipMasq": true, "hairpinMode": true, "ipam": { "type": "host-local
", "subnet": "10.244.0.0/16" } } ] }
```

**$1-k8s.conf**

```
{
"cniVersion": "0.3.1",
"name": "bridge",
"type": "bridge",
"bridge": "bridge",
"addIf": "true",
"isDefaultGateway": true,
"forceAddress": false,
"ipMasq": true,
"hairpinMode": true,
"ipam": {
"type": "host-local",
"subnet": "10.244.0.0/16"
}
}
```

**$87-podman-bridge.conflist**

```
{
"cniVersion": "0.4.0",
"name": "podman",
"plugins": [
{
"type": "bridge",
"bridge": "cni-podman0",
"isGateway": true,
"ipMasq": true,
"hairpinMode": true,
"ipam": {
"type": "host-local",
"routes": [{ "dst": "0.0.0.0/0" }],
"ranges": [
[
{
"subnet": "10.88.0.0/16",
"gateway": "10.88.0.1"
}
]
]
}
},
{
"type": "portmap",
"capabilities": {
"portMappings": true
}
},
{
"type": "firewall"
},
{
"type": "tuning"
}
]
}
```

**$multus.kubeconfig**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: local
  cluster:
    server: https://[10.96.0.1]:443
    certificate-authority-data: .....
users:
- name: multus
  user:
    token: .....
contexts:
- name: multus-context
  context:
    cluster: local
    user: multus
current-context: multus-context

File of '/etc/cni/multus/net.d'

**NetworkAttachment info:**

    cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
    apiVersion: "k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1"
    kind: NetworkAttachmentDefinition
    metadata:
    name: macvlan-conf
    spec:
    config: '{
    "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
    "type": "macvlan",
    "master": "eth1",
    "mode": "bridge",
    "ipam": {
    "type": "host-local",
    "subnet": "192.168.1.0/24",
    "rangeStart": "192.168.1.200",
    "rangeEnd": "192.168.1.216",
    "routes": [
    { "dst": "0.0.0.0/0" }
    ],
    "gateway": "192.168.1.1"
    }
    }'
    EOF
```

**Pod yaml info:**

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: samplepod
annotations:
k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: macvlan-conf
spec:
containers:
    name: samplepod
    command: ["/bin/ash", "-c", "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"]
    image: alpine
    EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed new minikube version, now adding secondary interface seems to be fine.